# R copy row and divide value with duplicate ids

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
id val
a  10
a  50
b  30
```

Now for every id, I want to divide val by the number of repetitions of id and copy the row just as many times. So the final dataframe will become like so:

```
id val
a  5
a  5
a  25
a  25
b  30
```

Please note that the duplicate ids may not be consecutive.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(val = val/n()) %>%
 uncount(n())

  id      val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         5
2 a         5
3 a        25
4 a        25
5 b        30
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the counts in a vector and use it to repeat the data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(id=c("a","a","b"),val=c(10,50,30))
df$id = as.character(df$id)
n = table(df$id)
with(df,data.frame(id=rep(id,n[id]),val=rep(val/n[id],n[id])))

  id val
1  a   5
2  a   5
3  a  25
4  a  25
5  b  30
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tapply` and `stack`.

```
stack(with(d, tapply(val, id, function(x) rep(x/length(x), each=length(x)))))
#   values ind
# 1      5   a
# 2      5   a
# 3     25   a
# 4     25   a
# 5     30   b
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "b"), val = c(10L, 50L, 30L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```